# Correct ticks in pgfplots' colorbar if heatmap's z is logarithmic

Tags: pgfplots

I try to draw a heatmap using pgfplots, but **I can not get correct tick values in a colorbar accompanying the heatmap if z is logarithmic**. What is the source of the values around 10^-11? There is nothing similar in the data file.

The file

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{map.txt}
    0.1 0   2.933100901655603E-6    
    0.1 10  1.2378929491530841E-5   
    0.1 20  2.0588051604902755E-5   
    0.1 30  2.7190941686966532E-5   
    0.1 40  3.290721897852047E-5    
    0.1 60  4.250275971734089E-5    
    0.1 80  5.0350197981567186E-5   
    0.1 100 5.681643648591518E-5    
    0.1 150 6.859558257512272E-5    
    0.1 200 7.652271637806553E-5    
    0.1 250 8.22752949739641E-5 
    0.1 300 8.668070617985642E-5    

    0.2 0   1.362157048411715E-5    
    0.2 10  1.4186557576426701E-5   
    0.2 20  1.9510106350903664E-5   
    0.2 30  2.3880991840192088E-5   
    0.2 40  2.7472817836855655E-5   
    0.2 60  3.282892845070262E-5    
    0.2 80  3.656164586607819E-5    
    0.2 100 3.944614546159667E-5    
    0.2 150 4.434691145348564E-5    
    0.2 200 4.730750444203243E-5    
    0.2 250 4.9180711846180925E-5   
    0.2 300 5.0512424521156164E-5   
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    view={0}{90},
    zmode=log]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=2] {map.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the following image:

[image: heatmap]

Comment: please don't use jet. Consider anything else.

Comment: but what is jet?

Comment: @percusse ok it is a color scheme. I just used the default and wanted to change it because of the somewhat flat blue part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### New Answer

A simple solution to what you want is to *not* use a logarithmic z-axis directly, but to calculate that values using `z expr=log10(\thisrowno{2})`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents}{map.txt}
    0.1 0   2.933100901655603E-6
    0.1 10  1.2378929491530841E-5
    0.1 20  2.0588051604902755E-5
    0.1 30  2.7190941686966532E-5
    0.1 40  3.290721897852047E-5
    0.1 60  4.250275971734089E-5
    0.1 80  5.0350197981567186E-5
    0.1 100 5.681643648591518E-5
    0.1 150 6.859558257512272E-5
    0.1 200 7.652271637806553E-5
    0.1 250 8.22752949739641E-5
    0.1 300 8.668070617985642E-5

    0.2 0   1.362157048411715E-5
    0.2 10  1.4186557576426701E-5
    0.2 20  1.9510106350903664E-5
    0.2 30  2.3880991840192088E-5
    0.2 40  2.7472817836855655E-5
    0.2 60  3.282892845070262E-5
    0.2 80  3.656164586607819E-5
    0.2 100 3.944614546159667E-5
    0.2 150 4.434691145348564E-5
    0.2 200 4.730750444203243E-5
    0.2 250 4.9180711846180925E-5
    0.2 300 5.0512424521156164E-5
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/jet,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            shader=interp,
        ] table [
            x index=0,
            y index=1,
            z expr=log10(\thisrowno{2}),    % <-- this does what you want
        ] {map.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

### Old Answer (to Old Question)

PGFPlots is exactly doing what you are telling it to do. Your data file contains values of the range 2.9e-6 to 8.7e-5. If you write `yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$` you get exactly that. so instead of just the values 2,4,...,8 and the multiplier 10^-5 on top of the colorbar you get 10^2,10^4,...,10^8. If you in addition have `zmode=log` you of course get as `\tick` ln(value) which gives for values around 10^-5 -11, but because of `yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$` it is written 10^-11 ...

So simply comment the two lines causing the trouble and everything should be fine, right?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\begin{filecontents}{map.txt}
    0.1 0   2.933100901655603E-6
    0.1 10  1.2378929491530841E-5
    0.1 20  2.0588051604902755E-5
    0.1 30  2.7190941686966532E-5
    0.1 40  3.290721897852047E-5
    0.1 60  4.250275971734089E-5
    0.1 80  5.0350197981567186E-5
    0.1 100 5.681643648591518E-5
    0.1 150 6.859558257512272E-5
    0.1 200 7.652271637806553E-5
    0.1 250 8.22752949739641E-5
    0.1 300 8.668070617985642E-5

    0.2 0   1.362157048411715E-5
    0.2 10  1.4186557576426701E-5
    0.2 20  1.9510106350903664E-5
    0.2 30  2.3880991840192088E-5
    0.2 40  2.7472817836855655E-5
    0.2 60  3.282892845070262E-5
    0.2 80  3.656164586607819E-5
    0.2 100 3.944614546159667E-5
    0.2 150 4.434691145348564E-5
    0.2 200 4.730750444203243E-5
    0.2 250 4.9180711846180925E-5
    0.2 300 5.0512424521156164E-5
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/jet,
        colorbar,
%        colorbar style={yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
%        zmode=log,
    ]
        \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=2] {map.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks, but why "of course it uses ln(x)"? It is the first drawing package I know which defaults do a natural logarithm, and it seems charts which use natural logarithms are rarer.

Comment: The PGFPlots v1.15 manual states in [section 4.2 on page 41](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=41): "The logarithmic scaling means to apply the natural logarithm (base e) to each [...] coordinate. Furthermore,
ticks will be typeset as 10^<exponent>, [...]" ...

Comment: Ok but I want the logarithmic scale, and without that line "causing trouble" I get ticks like -11. Now I guess I should go search whether there is some switch to make pgfplots use the common logarithm or put somewhere into pgfplots' macros a conversion to common logarithms or lookup tex' calculating capabilities
, because your answer does not quite answer this.

Comment: Correct, *this* isn't answered (yet), because up to now you never asked for that :) Do you want to ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) or do you want to edit this question?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope that it is now clearer and more focused.